# Can i reprogram a usb receiver?

Tags: usb, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech G903 Lightspeed mouse and I lost the USB receiver to it and was curious to see if I can reprogram another Logitech mouse receiver to work for the G903.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Not at all likely (99%) so you either have to get a new receiver from LogiTech (if they have one) or a new mouse.

Comment: What research have you done regarding this? Logitech has pretty decent support docs, and while they do have several different types of USB receivers, so long as you have the compatible type there's no reason it should not work to communicate with the keyboard. We do expect people to have tried a few things and done some research, and to show what they have learned and tried. Adding that info will greatly improve your question, and if you haven't yet done either of those, please do so.

Answer (score 3):

You can pair your ***Logitech G903 LIGHTSPEED Wireless Mouse*** with any **Logitech LIGHTSPEED USB Receiver** (but not with other Logitech receivers, like the *Bolt* or *Unifying* receivers.)

To pair your mouse with a new receiver (of the correct type!) you would use the ***Logitech Connection Utility*** https://support.logi.com/hc/en-my/articles/360025141574 (or possibly also using *Logitech G HUB* as outlined in https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/7709072311959)

Answer (score 1):

Logitech Unify mice, keyboards and tranceivers can be re-paired (in arbitrary combinations) using a utility that can be downloaded from Logitech.

In some cases a (non-Unify) mouse or keyboard can be re-paired with a another receiver from the same model/series, but as far as I know that was only valid for very old models (>15 years old). And the required pairing utilities (series specific) don't work on recent Windows versions (Windows 7 was the last one I think) and are very hard to find (not available from Logitech anymore).

For all other Logitech devices it can't be done.

Your G903 is not a Unify model and there doesn't seem to be a pairing utility available on the Logitech web-site for this model, so I think you are out of luck on this one.

Comment: Logitech has a few different types of USB receivers, for reasons only they know. Unifying is not the only type.